Cannot see components correctly in my custom modal
I am desperately seeking for help as I cannot figure out how to solve a problem in my Angular application,
I have created a custom modal:
modal.component.html
<div class="modal {{ size }}">
  <lib-card [background]="'#FFF'">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <lib-button [size]="'small'" [variant]="'secondary'">Cancel</lib-button>
        <lib-button [size]="'small'" (click)="submit()">Save</lib-button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </lib-card>
</div>

<div class="modal-backdrop" (click)="close()"></div>

modal.component.ts
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonComponent, CardComponent } from 'tgtr-fe-comp-lib';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ButtonComponent, CardComponent],
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrl: './modal.component.scss',
})
export class ModalComponent {
  @Input() size? = 'md';
  @Input() title? = 'Modal title';

  @Output() closeEvent = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() submitEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  close(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.remove();
    this.closeEvent.emit();
  }

  submit(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.remove();
    this.submitEvent.emit();
  }
}

modal.service.ts
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import {
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  Inject,
  Injectable,
  Injector,
  TemplateRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
  private modalNotifier?: Subject<string>;
  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  ) {}

  open(content: TemplateRef<any>, options?: { size?: string; title?: string }) {
    this.document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    const modalComponentFactory =
      this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent);
    const contentViewRef = content.createEmbeddedView(null);
    const modalComponent = modalComponentFactory.create(this.injector, [
      contentViewRef.rootNodes,
    ]);

    modalComponent.instance.size = options?.size;
    modalComponent.instance.title = options?.title;
    modalComponent.instance.closeEvent.subscribe(() => this.closeModal());
    modalComponent.instance.submitEvent.subscribe(() => this.submitModal());

    modalComponent.hostView.detectChanges();

    this.document.body.appendChild(modalComponent.location.nativeElement);
    this.modalNotifier = new Subject();
    return this.modalNotifier?.asObservable();
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.modalNotifier?.complete();
    this.document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
  }

  submitModal() {
    this.modalNotifier?.next('confirm');
    this.closeModal();
  }
}

Everything outside the ng-content is correctly displayed, however, all the custom components inside are not. Ex, my custom p component is missing the bold style. My custom input component are not displayed at all, or my radio button component only display the radio.
MyComponentWithModalCall.component.html
<div class="itinerary">
  <div class="head">
    <lib-h1 [bold]="true">Itinerary</lib-h1>
    <lib-p [bold]="true" [responsive]="true"
      >A visual itinerary shows customers exactly where they’ll go and what
      they’ll do during your activity.
    </lib-p>
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <lib-button [fill]="true" [variant]="'secondary'"
      >Add Meeting / Pickup Point</lib-button
    >
  </div>
  <button (click)="openModal(modalTemplate)">Open Modal</button>
</div>

<ng-template #modalTemplate>
  <app-itinerary-modal />
</ng-template>

MyComponentWithModalCall.component.ts
import { Component, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ButtonComponent,
  Heading1Component,
  InputComponent,
  ParagraphComponent,
  RadioComponent,
} from 'tgtr-fe-comp-lib';
import { ModalService } from '../../modal/modal.service';
import { ItineraryModalComponent } from './itinerary-modal/itinerary-modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-itinerary',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    Heading1Component,
    ParagraphComponent,
    ButtonComponent,
    InputComponent,
    RadioComponent,
    ItineraryModalComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './itinerary.component.html',
  styleUrl: './itinerary.component.scss',
})
export class ItineraryComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {}

  openModal(modalTemplate: TemplateRef<any>) {
    console.log(modalTemplate);
    this.modalService
      .open(modalTemplate, { size: 'lg', title: 'Add location' })
      .subscribe((action) => {
        console.log('modalAction', action);
      });
  }
}

I get no errors in my console. Here is a picture of the html inspection from the browser
Browser html structure screenshot
I would be grateful for any help!
I have tried asking chatGPT to figure out if something was missing in my modal.service, I also tried changing the encapsulation.

Can you provide a codesandbox so it would be easier to help out?

It's unclear what you expect to project inside app-modal with
<ng-content></ng-content>.
You should inject with the template call:
<app-modal><ng-content to be projected should be placed here></app-modal>.

So, I solved the issue with <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet
